# How to define metric d' in the following example?

Tags: dynamical-systems

In Peter Walters'- An Introduction to Ergodic Theory, I'm fine with rest of all, but unable to define metric d'. How this metric should be defined ? Any idea or approach?

[image]

Comment: I can't make sense of this. I dk what he means by "$T$ is an isometry for $d'\;$" but it's clearly not the usual meaning.

Answer (score 3):

What the author seems to be getting at, is essentially that you can define a
piecewise linear homeomorphism $h: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$h(2x) = h(x) + 1$ and then take $d'(x, y) = |h(x) - h(y)|$.
That looks possible, but overcomplicated.

Instead, I would suggest defining $d''(x,y) = \left|\log x  - \log y\right|$. This
metric is topologically equivalent to $d$ because 
$\log: (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism, but it is not
uniformly equivalent because $\log$ is not uniformly continuous.
It is easy to see that for any $a > 0$ the mapping $T_a: x \mapsto ax$
is an isometry with respect to $d''$, since
$$
d''(ax, ay) = \left|(\log a + \log x) - (\log a + \log y)\right| =
              \left|\log x - \log y\right| = d''(x, y).
$$

Comment: Well that's great !! Thanks a lot !